# How Can I Find The Length Of Text To Speech Generated By pyttsx3 Without Generating The mp3 File?

Tags: python-3.x, mp3, pyttsx3

I'm trying to make a bot to generate videos with text to speech, but I need to know the duration of text the text to speech without already generating it.

I'm using a speaking rate of 175, and the `engine.getProperty('voices')[0]`: male voice.

I've tried looking on the internet, but all I found was how to get the length of the TTS post-generation. I also tried doing some simple math but that didnt work either, the answers were too inaccurate and I'm trying to get 10~100 millisecond precision.